# Robotium : Test cases are skipped while executing robotium scripts

Tags: robotium

I am using robotium, i am facing an issue while executing test scripts. My Entire test suite takes 3- 4 hrs of execution, The issues faced are as follows:

1. Some of the test cases are skipped while execution.
2. Device gets disconnected  and reconnected multiple times while execution is in progress.
3. Observed the above issues on multiple devices.

Any one facing similiar issue any solution for this ?

Comment: Possible Causes:

 1. Some of the test cases are skipped while execution.
 Answer: Check if the test methods getting skipped are not started with 'test' keyword

2. Device disconnection might be because of loose USB port of the system.

Comment: Are there any logcat messages that explain what's going on?